# wx.Media video load ....Video file not playing

Tags: python

I want to start playing a .wmv file as soon as it is loaded in wxPython. I wrote a small code for it. The code does not give any error, but it does not show any video as well, but the sound does play in the background. It just shows a gray screen. Following is the code I wrote for my program.

```
import wx 
import wx.media

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)

        # Create some controls
        try:
            self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.Destroy()
            raise
        self.mc.Load(r"C:\Documents and Settings\N1002401B\Desktop\test1.wmv")
        #self.slider.SetRange(0, self.mc.Length())
        #folder, filename = os.path.split("C:\Documents and Settings\N1002401B\Desktop\test1.wmv")
        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.OnPlay)
    def OnPlay(self,evt):
        self.mc.Play()

app = wx.App(0)

frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = TestPanel(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

I am using Python 2.7 and windows XP.

Can anyone please help me on this one. I would be really grateful for your help.